# How to maintain the size of webpage to be same in every browser/full screen?

Tags: html, css, width

I've written my html and it looks perfectly nice in Google Chrome
but when I look on Firefox, it has white space at the bottom. When I go full screen, it also has white space at bottom.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

My code:

```
.mainwrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image: url(../img/homebg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: KaiTi, "Arial Unicode MS";
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to put the height of `html` and `body` at `100%`. As well as `padding: 0` and `margin: 0` should be in the `html` and `body` styles to ensure that there are no unwanted borders.

```
.mainwrapper {
    background: url(bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: KaiTi, "Arial Unicode MS";
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #000;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I think you don't understand the concept of the `div`. If you would want a fullscreen background then you should apply the background image to the `body` style like this:

```
body {
    background: url(bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
     }
```

You should use an div as big as the screen to fill it with a background image. Thats why you have the body. And then the image will move while scrolling and you have no white borders at all.

If you however still want to use the `div` which is used for parts of the website not as an substitute for body then you have to deal with the fact that it won't move while scrolling (except you have a script for it).

Comment: it solve, but... now when the browser get smaller, the below part(when scroll down) will become white...
how can i solve it?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Summary: is use `body` for background images. Then you won't have borders with images. Because they are not infinitely big and will end.